# UnauthorizedAccessException on pdb trying to debug a unit test

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, f#, xunit

If I put a single breakpoint on this method, on the last line, and debug via "Debug selected tests" in the Test Explorer, I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` on the pdb of the test assembly and the test aborts.

```
module Tests

open System
open Xunit

[<Fact>]
let fact () =
    let rng = Random ()
    let a = rng.Next() % 2 = 0
    let b = rng.Next() % 2 = 0
    a && b // <- breakpoint here
```

If I put a breakpoint anywhere else, I can debug fine. I can put a breakpoint on that line and debug if there's a breakpoint somewhere else in the method; the last breakpoint just appears empty (no generated code matches it). Note that the `&&` on the last line seems important, if I remove it the problem goes away. For example this version doesn't exhibit the problem:

```
[<Fact>]
let fact () =
    let rng = Random ()
    let a = rng.Next() % 2 = 0
    let b = rng.Next() % 2 = 0
    let result = a && b
    result // can put a breakpoint anywhere and debug fine
```

I could not repro outside a particular solution containing many other projects that I work on, even using all the exact same references and App.config. I spent already quite some time trying to nail down the issue and am looking for tips at this point. Here they are anyway:

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xunit.methodDisplay" value="method"/>
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="xunit.core" publicKeyToken="8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.3179" newVersion="2.1.0.3179" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FSharp.Core" version="4.0.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3 (Version 14.0.25424.00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of guesswork, but the `a && b` is an expression rather than a statement, so the breakpoint doesn't get hit. 
If the test runner has made a shadow copy of your assembly and PDB, then it might try to delete it after the test completes - but the debugger is still accessing it, leading to the exception.

Comment: I added `<add key="xunit.shadowCopy" value="false"/>` to my App.config and that indeed gets rid of the `UnauthorizedAccessException`!  There's still an `InvalidOperationException` in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll` saying `The cancelation of the test run is not possible as there is no test run which is in progress.`, but the test completes normally.

Comment: Glad to hear that fixed it. I've often seen test runners producing (handled) exceptions, but not causing problems other than inconvenience while debugging with break-on-throw!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on the same bitness (using 32bit xunit runner for a 32 bit project), I'm guessing the reason this is breaking is because unit tests should have signature: `unit -> unit` or in C# terms `void`.

If you change your first example to return unit, I was able to debug `a && b` with no issues. Now as to why your second example works even though it has the same return type, I have no idea. Maybe the bug is related to needing to assign a variable to be able do stuff with it in xunit?

```
[<Fact>]
let fact () =
    let rng = Random ()
    let a = rng.Next() % 2 = 0
    let b = rng.Next() % 2 = 0
    a && b // <- breakpoint here works
    ()
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the original test was an FsCheck.Xunit `[<Property>]` test, which should return bool; that's when I noticed the issue. I just simplified it down to not using FsCheck at all.